# Can't delete fields from content type

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

Whenever I try to delete **ANY** field from **ANY** content type I get the following error:

```
Uncaught PHP Exception Drupal\\Core\\Database\\DatabaseExceptionWrapper: "SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'drupal.field_deleted_data_35ab99eaa1' doesn't exist: SELECT DISTINCT t.entity_id AS entity_id\nFROM \n{field_deleted_data_35ab99eaa1} t\nWHERE bundle = :db_condition_placeholder_0\nLIMIT 10 OFFSET 0; Array\n(\n    [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => slider_images\n)\n" at /var/www/html/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Database/Connection.php line 685
```

The only difference being the table hash data, I.E. deleted_data_xxxx, each field i try to delete is referencing a different table. I've tried reinstalling Drupal and reimporting my configuration but no luck.

Any suggestions?

UPDATE:
After checking the database there are many of these tables:
field_deleted_revision_df347fb61b
and
field_deleted_df347fb61b

If that makes any difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I experienced this also, dig down the code. I found this all reason why fields not deleted after you did, the following:

- executing cron gazillion times

---

The entries in `field_config` and `field_config_instance` have probably a value of **1** in the deleted column.

This means they're marked for deletion, but won't actually be deleted until you run cron (deleted field data is purged in `field_cron()`).

As an alternative to running cron to remove deleted data, you can manually run `field_purge_batch($batch_size)`.

The `$batch_size` to use will vary depending on your server environment and needs. I've used values as low a 5 and as high as 10000.

[Here more informations](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21field%21field.purge.inc/function/field_purge_batch/8.4.x) about the `field_purge_batch()` function.

---

Here a possible solution to resolve your issue, but **backup your database first**. Don't be lazy, it will save your ass, if something goes wrong.

**using drush:**

```
drush eval "field_purge_batch(500)"
```

you might have to run a few times, or increase the `$batch_size` then there might still be `field_deleted` and `field_deleted_revision` tables, even after running cron

**using SQL query:**

```
SELECT * FROM `field_config` WHERE `deleted` = 1
SELECT * FROM `field_config_instance` WHERE `deleted` = 1
```

if you come up empty, you can safely delete those leftover tables.

Answer (score -1):

The only way I could resolve this was to create the missing table from the sql command line (using `drush sql-cli`), for example:

```
CREATE TABLE `field_deleted_data_XXX` (   
`bundle` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`deleted` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`entity_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`revision_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`langcode` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`delta` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`content_translation_source_value` varchar(12) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`,`deleted`,`delta`,`langcode`),
KEY `bundle` (`bundle`),
KEY `revision_id` (`revision_id`) );
```

Replacing `XXX` with the code that follows `field_deleted_data_` in the error message.  Then run:

```
drush php-eval 'field_purge_batch(1000);'
```

This may generate the error with a new code.  I had to go through the process 3 times, but eventually it resolved the error.